# Cannot read properties of undefined function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, weather-api

I am creating a weather app using ReactJS. Following is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      temp: ""
    };
    this.getLocation = this.getLocation.bind(this);
    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getLocation();
  }
  getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Not supported");
    }
    function success(position) {
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      lon = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(lat,lon);
      this.getWeather();
    }
    function error() {
      console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
    }
  }
  getWeather() {
    fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${api}&q=${lat},${lon}&aqi=no`)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((item) => {
      console.log(item);
    });
  }
```

api, lat and lon are constants I declared and initialized before this. This is giving the error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getWeather')
    at success
```

Comment: by the way, `lat and lon are constants ... before this` is not possible, since you are assigning a value to them after they've been declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function success(position) {
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      lon = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(lat,lon);
      this.getWeather();
    }
```

`this` here refers to the `success function` scope

use arrow function

```
success=(position)=>{
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      lon = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(lat,lon);
      this.getWeather();
}
```

or modify the whole code to

```
 getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Not supported");
    }
    const that = this; // now variable 'that' has the reference of 'this'
    function success(position) {
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      lon = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(lat,lon);
      that.getWeather();
    }
    function error() {
      console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but now it's saying 'success is not defined'

Comment: You are calling success before its initialization, try moving code outside or move to top